# How to reformat date in needed way in kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

I have this kind of response `2023-04-04 21:00:00` but I need to show to the user this kind of text `04/04 21:00`. Is there a simple way to reformat original date to simplify the final result in Kotlin?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SimpleDateFormatter](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/icu/text/SimpleDateFormat) to parse and format dates from and to strings.

From the docs:

> SimpleDateFormat is a concrete class for formatting and parsing dates in a locale-sensitive manner. It allows for formatting (date -> text), parsing (text -> date), and normalization.

Here is an example on how to use it to match your use case:

```
// We will use this instance to parse a string into a date
val inputDateFormatter = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.getDefault())
// We'll use this one to format the date into the desired string
val outputDateFormatter = SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd HH:mm", Locale.getDefault())val parsedDate = inputDateFormatter.parse("2023-04-04 21:00:00")

val parsedDate = inputDateFormatter.parse("2023-04-04 21:00:00")
val formattedDateString = outputDateFormatter.format(parsedDate)
```

Note that I'm using Locale.getDefault to parse the dates but you can change to use another locale if needed